# How do you write the symbol of Sun in Mathematica?

Tags: symbols

How do you write the symbol of Sun in Mathematica?

It is a circle with a small dot in the center (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_symbols#Sun))

Comment: `\[Sun]` gives the sun symbol